# Recurring background job error 9101/9104 auto create stats

Tags: sql-server-2012

I was spelunking through a quick trace on SQL 2012 SP3 CU3 when I noticed the database engine is generating thousands of these internal notifications every hour or so and in large chunks. I've also reproduced it in Extended Events but they do not add any additional information.

[image: Profiler]

I'm aware that auto create stats can timeout when queries timeout, but I checked and the database is configured to create them asynchronously (so that could not be the cause).

[image: Configuration]

I came across [this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e75ed5fc-b96a-450c-9363-547f3adc6f00/error-9104?forum=sqldatabaseengine) in reference to the error number explaining that auto create stats can fail due to deadlock or lack of resources, but I don't see any deadlocks recorded and the server is not resource constrained or under heavy load (CPU, memory ring buffers).

I had a look at the underlying table. It has a clustered identity primary key , mundane simple data types, is only about 4,000 rows and < 1MB in size. The indexes are nothing special. Integrity checks are fine. Stats are updated on a weekly schedule (a few days ago). Trace flags 2371 and 4199 are enabled.

Obviously these aren't real errors and don't surface anywhere but now I'm curious.

**Q. What could be going on to cause auto auto create stats to be triggered and also fail over and over in very quick succession?**

Thanks